How to Change the Accent (Tone/Rhythm) of Microphone Audio in Real-Time Using NAudio in C#?
I am building a C# application that captures live audio from the microphone and plays it back in real-time. My goal is to change the accent of the captured audio, such as altering its tone, rhythm, and overall speech characteristics to simulate different accents in real time.
I am using the NAudio library for audio capture and playback, but I'm unsure how to modify the voice characteristics (like accent) programmatically. I would like to change things like the rhythm, speed, and tone of the captured audio, but I'm not sure how to achieve this without using external APIs.
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Microphone
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private WaveInEvent waveIn;  // For capturing audio
    private BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;
    private WaveOutEvent waveOut;
    private bool isPlaying = false;
    SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void StartRecording()
    {
        try
        {
     var dialogResult = MessageBox. Show("Do you want to access your microphone?"), 
       "Microphone Access," MessageBoxButtons. YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
        WaveIn = new WaveInEvent
                {
         Default microphone device
                    WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1)  // Mono, 44.1kHz
                };

                bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat);
             WaveOut = new WaveOutEvent();

                waveIn.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;

                waveIn.StartRecording();
                MessageBox.Show("Recording started...");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Microphone access denied.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error starting recording: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            ProcessAudioData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error while streaming data: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void ProcessAudioData()
    {
        // Apply accent change to the audio data (adjust rhythm, speed, or tone)
        ChangeAccent(); 
        PlayAudioChunk();
    }

    private void ChangeAccent()
    {
        // Example of simulating an accent change (altering rhythm and tone)
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes];
        bufferedWaveProvider.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 2) // Assuming 16-bit PCM audio
        {
            short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, i);

            // Simulate accent change by modifying the sample rhythm or tone
            // For example: adjust the amplitude or speed of the samples
            // (This is a simplified approach; a more complex model would require 
           advanced signal processing techniques.)

            sample = (short)(sample * 1.1f); // Slightly boost volume or simulate 
            rhythm change

            // Ensure the sample doesn't overflow
            if (sample > short.MaxValue) sample = short.MaxValue;
            if (sample < short.MinValue) sample = short.MinValue;

            // Write the adjusted sample back to the buffer
            byte[] adjustedBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(sample);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(adjustedBytes, 0, buffer, i, 2);
        }

        // After applying the accent change, write the modified data back to the 
       provider
        bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    private void PlayAudioChunk()
    {
        try
        {
            // Only play if there is data available
            if (bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes > 0 && !isPlaying)
            {
                if (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
                {
                    AdjustVolume(100.0f);  // Optional: Adjust volume here
                    waveOut.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
                    waveOut.Play();
                    isPlaying = true; // Mark as playing
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error during playback: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void AdjustVolume(float volumeFactor)
    {
        // Adjust the volume of the audio data before playback
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes];
        bufferedWaveProvider.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // Modify the audio data to apply the volume adjustment
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 2) // Assuming 16-bit PCM audio
        {
            short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, i);

            // Apply the gain to the sample
            sample = (short) (sample * volumeFactor);

            // Ensure the sample doesn't overflow
            if (sample > short.MaxValue) sample = short.MaxValue;
            if (sample < short.MinValue) sample = short.MinValue;

            // Write the adjusted sample back to the buffer
            byte[] adjustedBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(sample);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(adjustedBytes, 0, buffer, i, 2);
        }

        // After adjusting the volume, write the modified data back to the provider
        bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    public void StopRecording()
    {
        try
        {
            waveIn.StopRecording();
            if (waveOut != null && waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                waveOut.Stop();
                isPlaying = false; Reset playing state
            }
            waveOut.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Recording stopped.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error stopping the recording: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StartRecording();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
          MessageBox. Show("Microphone access is denied. Please enable microphone 
          permissions in the Privacy settings.", "Error," MessageBoxButtons. OK, 
          MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", "Error", 
      MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

   Private void button Stop_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopRecording();
    }
}
}


I would expect this to be more of a research topic than a programming question. AutoTune mostly does pitch correction, a seemingly easier task, and I think its algorithm is secret, and quite valuable. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for such a question, but at best I would expect references to research papers, not examples of source code.
